# Laravel Cannot use 'DEL' with redis-cluster

Tags: laravel, redis

I'm using Redis as a cache and I'm trying to run `Cache::tags($tag)->flush()` on Laravel 6 when I encounter this error:

```
Cannot use 'DEL' with redis-cluster
```

What is the possible cause of this issue?

Comment: Have you fixed that?